# JQuery Function import html from external source

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have this JQuery function:

```
function addSomeHTML()
            {
                  $("#mysection").html("<div id='myid'>some content here</div>");
            }
```

I basically need this part: `<div id='myid'>some content here</div>` to be read from an external file.

Can anyone help please?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the [AJAX `load()` method](http://api.jquery.com/load/).

```
$('#mysection').load('yourfile.html');
```

Of course the URL can also point to a PHP script etc.

Comment: Excellent answer, a followup question...  how would i apply the formatting (css) to the newly incorporated code?

Comment: You can add a function as a second (or third if you provide any data) argument that's called once the content has loaded.